# recv all socket (until the message end symbol), C

Tags: c, sockets

I want to write a `recvall` function for socket in C. I assume, that every message in my protocol ends with `\r\n`. I wrote something like this below:

```
int recvall (int socket, char *buffer, int numBytes)
{
    int bytesRcvd = 0;
    numBytes = numBytes - 1;

    while(bytesRcvd < numBytes)
    {
        int chunk = recv(socket, buffer + bytesRcvd, numBytes - bytesRcvd, 0);

        if (chunk == 0 || chunk == -1)
            break;

        if(strstr(buffer, "\r\n"))
            break;

        bytesRcvd += (chunk);

    }
    buffer[bytesRcvd] = '\0';
    return bytesRcvd;
}
```

But it shows me that it returns and reads `0` bytes. On the other hand, when I remove:

```
if(strstr(buffer, "\r\n"))
            break;
```

it hangs. How to improve it?

Answer (score 3):

One mistake here is that `strstr` expects a zero-terminated string. A fix:

```
buffer[chunk] = 0;
if(strstr(buffer, "\r\n"))
    break;
```

However, there may be more data following `"\r\n"`, and that data gets lost here.

---

A common design pattern for receiving data is:

1. Have a class that maintains a connection with send/receive buffers.
2. When it has received data into the receive buffer, it calls a message parsing callback passing `buffer` and `buffer_size`.
3. The message parsing callback consumes all available *complete* messages in the buffer and returns the number of bytes consumed (as you do).
4. The message parsing callback calls another callback, passing a complete message to it.

Something like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int socket;

    // Message-parsing callback.
    size_t(*on_recv_cb)(void*, void*, size_t);
    void* on_recv_cb_data;

    unsigned char recv_buffer[256 * 1024];
    size_t recv_buffer_size; // Initialized with 0;
} Connection;

void Connection_on_socket_ready_for_read(Connection* self) {
    // Assumes a non-blocking socket. Read once to avoid starvation of other sockets.
    ssize_t received = read(self->socket, self->recv_buffer + self->recv_buffer_size, sizeof self->recv_buffer - self->recv_buffer_size);
    if(received > 0) {
        self->recv_buffer_size += received;
        size_t consumed = self->on_recv_cb(self->on_recv_cb_data, self->recv_buffer, self->recv_buffer_size);
        self->recv_buffer_size -= consumed;
        memmove(self->on_recv_cb_data, self->recv_buffer + consumed, self->recv_buffer_size);
    }
    else if(received < 0) {
        if(EAGAIN == errno)
            return;
        perror("error");
        // Handle error.
    }
    else {
        // Handle EOF.
    }
}

typedef struct {
    // Message callback.
    void(*on_message_cb)(void*, char*, size_t);
    void* on_message_cb_data;
} MessageParserCrLf;

size_t MessageParserCrLf_on_recv(void* cb_data, void* data, size_t data_size) {
    MessageParserCrLf* self = cb_data;
    char* message_begin = data;
    char* message_end = data;
    while(data_size - (message_end - (char*)data) >= 2) {
        if(message_end[0] == '\r' && message_end[1] == '\n') {
            message_end += 2;
            self->on_message_cb(self->on_message_cb_data, message_begin, message_end - message_begin);
            message_begin = message_end;
        }
        else {
            ++message_end;
        }
    }
    return message_begin - (char*)data;
}

void on_message(void* cb_data, char* message, size_t message_size) {
    (void)cb_data; // Unused here.
    printf("on_message: %.*s\n", (int)message_size, message);
}

int main() {
    MessageParserCrLf message_parser = {on_message, NULL};
    Connection connection = {0, MessageParserCrLf_on_recv, &message_parser, {}, 0};
    Connection_on_socket_ready_for_read(&connection);
}
```

Outputs:

```
[~/src/test]$ cat lines.txt 
abc
def
end

[~/src/test]$ ./test < lines.txt 
on_message: abc

on_message: def

on_message: end
```

Comment: So what do you suggest? How should I implement this `recvall` when I assume that my protocol uses `\r\n` to indicate the end of the message?

Comment: Could you perhaps provide some C code for what you have described? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If there is "\r\n" in the received buffer, the following line will break and end the while loop,

if(strstr(buffer, "\r\n")) break;

but bytesRcvd hasn't increased, so the function will return with bytesRcvd=0.

Try to put bytesRcvd increase before judging like this,

bytesRcvd += (chunk);

if(strstr(buffer, "\r\n"))

break;